# How to get the value of the key in the serializer in manytomanyfield in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem with displaying the data during serialization.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Paradigmn(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    paradigm = models.ForeignKey(Paradigmn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Programmer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='languages')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And this is my serializer:

```
from languages.models import Language, Paradigmn, Programmer

class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paradigms = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='paradigm.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'paradigms')

class ParadigmnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Paradigmn
        fields = ('id', 'name',)    

class ProgrammerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = LanguageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Programmer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'languages')
```

And this is the result:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ryan",
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Java",
            "paradigms": "Object-Oriented"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jean",
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Python",
            "paradigms": "Object-Oriented"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Michael",
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Elixir",
            "paradigms": "Functional"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to show on the languages array, the name of the language instead of the all the details of the language array. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: No need to have ` languages = LanguageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` in LanguageSerializer` than.  As self.name properly define in Language Model.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField

class ProgrammerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languagelist = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_languagelist(self, obj):
        return [{'name': i.name} for i in obj.languages.all()]

    class Meta:
        model = Programmer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'languagelist')
```

Comment: The solution is not working. It only returns:

[
    1,
    3,
    2
]